# Issue with odeint Python

Tags: python, scipy, ode, odeint

I am trying to use `odeint` but I have a parameter that changes values with every time step. My function is:

```py
def f(y, t, k1, k2, Pr):
    return k1*(Pr-k2)*y
```

Where `Pr` is a pandas series that contains float values, of which I have observed values. And `t` is a list of integer years from 1961 to 2014. I wrote the following code for `odeint`:

```py
y0 = 120000
k1 = 0.2
k2 = -.4
y = odeint(f, y0, t, args = (k1, k2, Pr, ))
```

But it gives the following error:

```
RuntimeError: The size of the array returned by func (54) does not match the size of y0 (1).
```

Comment: just pointing out a potential bug:`k1` and `k2` are overwritten in the first two lines of your function, so the values you're passing in for them are discarded.

Comment: @EricCanton you are right, i just edited the question

Comment: Could you let us know the types of `Pr` and `t`? e.g. Pandas DataFrame or Series. Or a simplified example showing their instantiation. It's important for getting the right syntax for working with them.

Comment: @EricCanton Pr is a pandas series that contains float values and t is the list that contains year values from 1961 to 2014. The length of both is 54.

Comment: The error you get simply highlights that `y0` is a single `int`, whereas the return value of `f` contains 54 elements. These two must have the same shape. If the initial value is the same for all 54 elements, then simply write `y0 = 1.2e5 * np.ones(54)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by the error message, `Pr` is being passed in as a vector of length 54, instead of the values one-by-one. Inferring that `Pr` is a NumPy vector, this would mean the output of `f` is the result of applying the `return` value elementwise to `Pr`.

To fix this, you can instead use a function that produces a `Pr` value from a time input. Again assuming that `Pr[k]` corresponds to `t[k]`, the simplest version of this function could be:

```
def get_Pr(time: float):
    t_index = sum(t <= time) - 1 
    return Pr[t_index]
```

Then modify `f` as follows:

```
def f(y, t, k1, k2):
    this_pr = get_Pr(t)
    return k1*(this_pr-k2)*y
```

**edit**: ...and then don't pass `Pr` in as an arg to `scipy.odeint`, since `f` gets the value in a different way.

Comment: When I do these changes and run the odeint, it gives the error- `TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers [1961.0000197468344] of <class 'float'>`

Comment: Not sure why this error comes. The `t` is time series from 1961-2014

Comment: It's strange that you're getting that error, if `t` is a list and not a NumPy array or Pandas series... `t <= time` should give a different error with a Python list, since `<=` isn't defined between a list and a float.

Comment: But that aside, to use an integer index with a Pandas series, use `.iloc` on it. As in, `return Pr.iloc[t_index]`

Comment: Pr(t) is available at discrete-time intervals (i.e. every year). Could this be a reason for getting the error that is in 1st comment? Are time values supposed to be continuous for odeint?